# android fragment viewmodel initialization failed

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to implement data-binding in android with kotlin:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container, false
        ) as FragmentLoginBinding
        val view: View = mBinding.root
        mBinding.login?.invoke(viewModel)
        return view
    }
```

But it says **lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized** on runtime. How can I resolve this ?

- Initializing in fragment will work
- It will better if you guys provide me with viewmodel initialized from parent, parent is an activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the thing worked for me :

```
mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container, false
        ) as FragmentLoginBinding
        val view: View = mBinding.root
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(AuthViewModel::class.java)
        mBinding.login = viewModel
        return view
```

In XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="login"
            type="com........." />
    </data>
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

If You want to init viewModel in Activity and use it in fragment You can do it in this way:

MainActvity.kt:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityVM

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityVM::class.java)

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

YourFragment.kt:

```
private lateinit var binding: YourFragmentBinding
private lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityVM

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View?
{
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_your, container, false
    )

    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MainActivityVM::class.java)

    //here You can use Your viewModel

    return binding.root
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`lateinit` properties require you to initialize them before the first use. The error happens only if it wasn't initialized. You can check if `lateinit` is initialized by using [`isInitialized`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/is-initialized.html) property of `KProperty0` interface.

```
val isReadyForUse = ::viewModel.isInitialized
```

Inside of a `Fragment` you can initialize a `ViewModel` using extension function `viewModels()`:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels

class YourFragment: Fragment {
    private val viewModel: YourViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

It's lazy-loaded, which means as soon as you'll try to access `viewModel` it will be initialized and returned. Next time no initialization will happen.

If you want to make your `ViewModel` class loaded in an `Activity` first and later in a `Fragment` use `activityViewModels()`.

*Note: after the first initialization of a `ViewModel` by `activityViewModels()` it will be stored in a `ViewModelStore` that is owned by `Activity`. To create new instance of a `YourViewModel` by using `activityViewModels()` you will have to finish your `Activity` or clear view model store `requireActivity().viewModelStore.clear()`*.

To initialize in an Activity and use a Fragment do next:

```
class YourActivity {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val viewModelInit = ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModel.javaClass)
    }
}
```

And in a `Fragment`:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels

class YourFragment: Fragment {
    private val viewModel: YourViewModel by activityViewModels()
}
```